# What should I look out for when developing for ios4

Tags: xcode, ios4, ios5

I have developed an app for ios 5 recently but when I was telling my friends about it some of them told me that they couldn't get it because their iphone/ipad didn't run ios 5 and they were not for what ever reason updating from ios 4. If I want to develop a new app for ios 4 what should I look out for as far as programming it goes?(NOTE: I have never worked in an environment in which I would need to worry about memory management)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is a big change that you need to make sure to account for when developing for iOS 4 instead of iOS 5. In addition check out:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1

for the specific changes between the SDKs